# If function with 8 conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the following tables:

[image: tables]

The first on the left is what I have after I manually write the data in excel. The second on the right is the reference table.

Basically what I want is a multiple-if function that allow me to recognize the aim of my training program.

For instance I did 3 sets and 10 repetitions with an intensity of 66% and a rest of 150 sec. Based on that I want a quick function that tells me if this program was designed for power, strength, endurance or hypertrophy.

If you have trouble reading the table on the right this can make you better understand how to read it: in order to training "Power Single" you should do from 2 to 6 sets with less or equal to 6 reps, intensity over 85% and rest from 120 to 300 seconds.

Thank you for your help

P.S. I believe the if function to be a good solution, anyway if you got something else feel free to tell me.

Comment: What if it matches multiple items? 4 sets, 2 reps, 87% and 120s-300s will match at least the first two, Power single and Power Multiple.

Comment: Yes but then i need to add other columns for strength hypertrophy endurance

Comment: Do you disregard the "Rest(s)" column? If you count it, your example doesn't meet all parts of the "Hypertrophy" row.

Comment: I think you need to give an example of what result your looking for. What is the answer to your first row of data? 3 sets and 10 reps match hypertrophy but then 66% matches endurance and 150 recs matches several. What classification should this data have?

Comment: Yes Jharoof, this is the issue, there are several matches values. Anyway if you look each row has something unique. For instance even though 150recs matches several the 1 RM for each training aim is different. Each row should be seen as a combination of all 4 parameters.

Comment: The title of your question seems oddly disconnected from the content of your question. Nothing about your question involves an `IF` function (in any specified way) or the number 8.

Comment: So can you give an example of what the answer is for the first one?

Comment: For your second example, what is the training program? I see Sets (6) and Reps (2) match for only "Power Single", but there's nothing further for 55% "% RM", so what do you want the Training Aim for that to be? Is there a "default" one for if something doesn't fit that table?

Comment: John the answer below by Bruce can give you an idea of what i intented, he got it. If the training program (left table) doesn't satisy the training aim (right table) then i'm not doing good. In other word if i believe that what i'm training is good for power but the table on the right doesn't confirm it, then i'm doing something different that might be endurance, hypertrophy or other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula I was able to put together that works.  Note though, it only works if the right four variables exist in your table. You can, of course, put an `IfError()` around it to return what you want if it doesn't match.

One note: In order for this to work, you need to "break out" the numerical ranges into two columns, as you will see in the screenshot.  This is because the lookup will search two columns, to find where a number falls in between.

The yellow line is my own line, to show that if a "mix" is matched correctly, it'll return a training aim:

[image]

First, I'll break the formula down. It's basically a combination of a bunch of "If()" statements multiplied together. (Sorry, but I'm not quite sure how it works, so someone else may kindly comment on that!)

`=INDEX(G2:G6,MATCH(1,IF(A2>=H2:H6,IF(A2<=I2:I6,1)),0))`

So, your Index is going to be set in G2:G6.  The `If()` statement in the `Match()` will return the row where your `Set` is found in the range. (The two parts to this are why you need to create the two columns for the ranges).

Then, you just repeat that `If()` statement, changing the parameters to match the new data you want to match.  Voila! Enter as an array, with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$6,MATCH(1,(IF($B2>=$J$2:$J$6,IF($B2<=$K$2:$K$6,1))*IF($A$2>=$H$2:$H$6,IF($A2<=$I$2:$I$6,1))*IF($C2>=$L$2:$L$6,IF($C2<=$M$2:$M$6,1))*IF($D2>=$N$2:$N$6,IF($D2<=$O$2:$O$6,1))),0)),"No exact match found")`

Or, another option for better legibility, is to name the ranges. Then it could look like this:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Training_Aim,MATCH(1,(IF($B2>=Sets_Min,IF($B2<=Sets_Max,1))*IF($A$2>=Reps_Min,IF($A2<=Reps_Max,1))*IF($C2>=RM_Min,IF($C2<=RM_Max,1))*IF($D2>=Rest_Min,IF($D2<=Rest_Max,1))),0)),"No exact match found")`

Comment: Whe i write the first if formula i knly got all "not exact match found"

Comment: @AngM - Did you adjust the ranges, if necessary? Did you make sure that the data *will* return one?  What if you use the numbers in my example, does it still not work?

Comment: Yes i did the same example ! i don't know how to put a screenshot here to show you the result.

Comment: @AngM -  You can just take a screenshot (on Windows, you could even use the Snipping tool), then upload to a site such as www.imgur.com (or use the image icon in the post tool on Stack Overflow).  Also, you're entering this with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, correct?  Make sure that the logic is correct in the formula, it's easy to accidentally miss that.

Comment: @AngM - thanks! Ah, how did you enter the "% 1 RM" info in your column C?  Is that `66` or `.66` ?  In my example, it's just `66`.  If you want to use `.66` (which does make sense, obvioulsy since it's a percentage), then in your columns L and M, change the numbers from say `85` to `.85` (you can leave `99999`).  That should do the trick I believe.

Comment: Can you send me the file ? Otherwise we can go on and on with comments.

Comment: I can't send you the file. Yes, we can go on and on, but we expect you to try things and think critically.  Plus, this is good for you to learn ("teach a man to fish" and whatnot).  First, can you try using the four variables that I used in my yellow line? Make sure to enter the percentage as "79", and not "*.*79" - if that works, then it's just a matter of tweaking how the percentages are entered/shown. If it doesn't work, then there are other issues we need to fix.

Comment: I said about the file because the forum doesn't like that much extended discussions in comments. Anyway this is the formula, when i use yours it tells me to make some changes. In particular it adds the * sign after the first 1. I understand the change about the % i believe to be not the problem. `=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$6;MATCH(1*(IF($B2>=$J$2:$J$6;IF($B2<=$K$2:$K$6;1))*IF($A$2>=$H$2:$H$6;IF($A2<=$I$2:$I$6;1))*IF($C2>=$L$2:$L$6;IF($C2<=$M$2:$M$6;1))*IF($D2>=$N$2:$N$6;IF($D2<=$O$2:$O$6;1)));0));"No exact match found")`

Comment: @angm did you try changing the percentage numbers as I described? Or do you just *think* that's not the issue?

Comment: @angm, oh! There's a typo in your formula. It should be `match(1, ...` not `match(1* ...`

Comment: Problem not solved yet, this is the same formula you used and i don't know why it doesn't work. [ http://imgur.com/Y8bP5ym ]

Comment: @AngM - you're entering it as an array formula, yeah? by pressing CTRL SHIFT ENTER, instead of just ENTER?

Answer (score 0):

Consider an SQL solution where you run a [cross join query](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) between both ranges which will return any combinations that match your needs. Excel can run SQL queries within a workbook using VBA ADO and the Jet/ACE Engine.

To implement below, move one table into a tab, `Workout` and the other in another tab, `TrainingAim` and run the macro. You will need to break up ranges into min and max. Multiple matches will stack on top of each other as results show. But according to posted data, one training matched: Power Single.

**Workout**

```
Sets    Reps    PctIRM      Recovery
3       10      0.66        150
6       2       0.55        300
2       13      0.35        150
3       15      0.45        300
6       6       0.9         150
2       4       0.85        300
5       2       0.75        300
3       11      0.65        400
1       13      0.6         450
2       6       0.7         150
```

**TrainingAim**

```
TrainingAim     SetsMin SetsMax RepsMin RepsMax PctIRMmin  PctIRMmax RestMin    RestMax
Power Single    2        6      6       999      0.85      1         120        300
Power Multiple  3        5      1       2        0.8       0.9       120        300
Strength        3        5      3       5        0.75      0.85      120        300
Hypertrophy     3        6      6       12       0.67      0.85      30     90
Endurance       2        3      12      999      0.67      1         0     30
```

**VBA Macro**

```
Sub RunSQL()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;"
    'strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" _
                      '& "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xls;"
    'strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                      '& "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
                      '& "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"        
    'strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
                      '& "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xls';" _
                      '& "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"  

    strSQL = " SELECT [Workout$].*, [TrainingAim$].*" _
                & " FROM [Workout$], [TrainingAim$]" _
                & " WHERE [Workout$].Sets BETWEEN [TrainingAim$].SetsMin AND [TrainingAim$].SetsMax" _
                & " AND [Workout$].Reps BETWEEN [TrainingAim$].RepsMin AND [TrainingAim$].RepsMax" _
                & " AND [Workout$].PctIRM BETWEEN [TrainingAim$].PctIRMmin AND [TrainingAim$].PctIRMmax" _
                & " AND [Workout$].Recovery BETWEEN [TrainingAim$].RestMin AND [TrainingAim$].RestMax;"

    ' OPEN THE CONNECTION
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' OUTPUT SQL RESULTS IN RESULTS TAB 
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
    conn.Close

    ' CLOSE THE CONNECTION
    MsgBox "Successfully ran SQL query!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " = " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**RESULTS**

```
Sets    Reps    PctIRM  Recovery  TrainingAim   SetsMin SetsMax RepsMin RepsMax PctIRMmin   PctIRMmax  RestMin  RestMax
6       6       0.9     150       Power Single  2       6       6       999     0.85        1          120      300
```

Comment: I really appreciate your work but i don't get how does the code work. Where do i need to paste it? Do i need a button? Honestly i'm a VBA beginner and i don't get it very well yet.

Comment: As mentioned, place your Workout data starting from A1 cell in tab `Workout` and TrainingAim data starting from A1 cell in tab `TrainingAim` tab. Then create a new tab, `Results` and in first row place all column headers of both tables (Sets - RestMax). Query results will begin at A2 cell.

Comment: Now for the code, press Alt-F11 to open the VBA IDE window, double click the `ThisWorkbook` object in upper left panel. Paste VBA code in white space on right. On menu bar, click Debug / Compile VBA project. Now return to main workbook and under View icon, find Macros (or Alt-F8) where `RunSQL` will now be available which you can select to run.

Comment: Ok now i got the meaning. Tab workload, trainingaim and result should be located each on different sheets? You said workout on A1, TrainingAim on A1 and result at A2.

Comment: Yes, three different sheets with exact names as I highlighted above (not Workload but Workout, and Results in plural).

Comment: Ok when i try to run the macro i got this message: -2147467529 = [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x168c Thread 0x1690 DBC 0x5ef8004

Comment: I was afraid that would happen. All depends on the odbc/oledb installed on your 32-bit/64-bit machine. See my edit where I add other connection strings. Uncomment out and try the Provider version ACE.OLEDB. Else, revert downward to an .xls version and try the other Driver/Provider pair.